# can i change "create url" in magento grid at "add new" button

Tags: magento, grid

What i want is to change the action for "add new" button

```
 class World_Exporter_Block_Adminhtml_Attribute extends    Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container{
    public function __construct()
    {

            $location = str_replace('new', 'newMap', $this->getCreateUrl());

            $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_attribute';
            $this->_blockGroup = 'exporter';
            $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('exporter')->__('Attribute Manager ');
            $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('exporter')->__('Add Item');





            parent::__construct();

            $this->setCreateUrl($location);

                $this->_addButton('add', array(
                 'label'     => $this->getAddButtonLabel() ,
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $location .'\')',
                'class'     => 'add',
             ));

            // echo $this->getCreateUrl();
    }
}
```

after trying so much i am still being able to change "newAction" to any other.. Plz help

Comment: Please describe a bit what you are actually trying to achieve... you want to change the add new action in all adminhtml grids? or just for  specific grid? describe it in a functional way: this is what is happening standard in magento and this is what I want to happen.

Comment: I already have assign "newAction" action to one of grid, i don't want any other button to bring me to the same "newAction" action. I think it make sense, "newAction" action is already in use. don't it? if you have much better solution just as if we can add another controller or something like that, i will appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

Yevgeny's answer is good but I would change some little things in his code :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_collection';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'story';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Manager');

    //Replace the first argument "add" by something else,
    //or both your new button and the original add button
    //won't be visible.
    $this->_addButton('btnAdd', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('story')->__('Add Item'),
        'onclick' => "setLocation('" . $this->getUrl('*/*/new', array('page_key' => 'collection')) . "')",
        'class' => 'add'
    ));

    //Moved parent's constructor here (not necessary I think)
    parent::__construct();

    //Remove original add button
    $this->_removeButton('add');
}
```

This line removes the original *add* button, leaving only your new button containing the new action :

```
$this->_removeButton('add');
```

**Note** : Be sure to remove the original button after the call to :

```
parent::__construct();
```

or the original button will stay in the Grid.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_collection';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'story';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Manager');
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_addButton('add', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('story')->__('Add Item'),
        'onclick' => "setLocation('" . $this->getUrl('*/*/new', array('page_key' => 'collection')) . "')",
        'class' => 'add'
    ));

}
```

Comment: change 
$this->getUrl('*/*/new', array('page_key' => 'collection')) 
to
$this->getUrl('*/*/newMap'))